# How to make two threads wait on each other to perform a task?

Tags: java, multithreading

While going through some problems on internet, I found this one. Not sure how to solve this.

I want thread-1 to run first and compute foo and wait, then want thread-2 to run and compute foo and finally want thread-1 to continue and print foo and complete execution.

I am thinking about it since last 1 hour and not able to solve. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

```
public class ThreadTest {

    private static class Thread01 extends Thread {

        private Thread02 _thread02; 
        public int foo = 0;

        public void setThread02(Thread02 thread02) {
            _thread02 = thread02;
        }

        public void run() {

            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) foo += i;
                synchronized (this) { this.notify(); }
                synchronized (_thread02) { _thread02.wait(); }
                System.out.println("Foo: " + _thread02.foo);
            } catch (InterruptedException ie) { ie.printStackTrace(); }
        }
    }


private static class Thread02 extends Thread {

        private final Thread01 _thread01; public int foo = 0;

        public Thread02(Thread01 thread01) {
            _thread01 = thread01;
        }

        public void run() {

            try {
                synchronized (_thread01) { _thread01.wait(); }
                foo = _thread01.foo;
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) foo += i;
                synchronized (this) { this.notify(); }
            } catch (InterruptedException ie) { ie.printStackTrace(); }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Thread01 thread01 = new Thread01();
        Thread02 thread02 = new Thread02(thread01);
        thread01.setThread02(thread02);

        thread01.start(); 
        thread02.start();
        thread01.join();
        thread02.join();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know why, but using underscores before field names makes me want to kill something!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without having looked much at your code I think it works like this:

Thread 1 computes foo, creates and starts Thread 2. Thread 1 calls `thread2.join()`. This has Thread 1 be suspended until Thread 2 finishes. Then just continue with the final code of Thread 1.

No notifications needed, just one simple `join()`.

Comment: You could at least look at the question =)

Comment: @Pescis There is none. And my answer does exactly what he wants to achieve.

Comment: I'm thinking this is a failed attempt at a SSSCE and that he actually wants to do something when thread2 is done computing foo (else the whole threading is utterly useless and could be done with one thread).

Comment: @Pescis You are totally right. The way he describes it it can be achieved with a simple join since he doesn't seem to want any concurrent execution.

Comment: Thanks for answer. However I was hoping to find some trick with wait/notify to achieve the same...  And yes multithreading is the requirement..it has to be run in parallel...at least till the point they can...

Answer (score 2):

One alternative to notify/wait code like this is to use `BlockingQueue` like [`LinkedBlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html).  With 2 `BlockingQueue`s, the two threads can wait for each other and pass messages back and forth without you writing the all of the wait and notify code which can be complex and fraught with bugs.